# Why does this helloworld haskell snippet fails to load?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I write a file named "baby.hs" with the following codes

```
bmiTell :: => Double -> String                                                  
bmiTell bmi                                                                     
 | bmi <= 1 = "small"                                                           
 | bmi <= 10 = "medium"                                                         
 | bmi <= 100 = "large"                                                         
 | otherwise = "huge"
```

When I load this file in `GHCi`, it complains like this:

```
ghci>:l baby.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( baby.hs, interpreted )

baby.hs:1:12: parse error on input ‘=>’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
ghci>
```

If I remove the `=>`, it doesn't work either:

```
bmiTell :: Double -> String                                                     
bmiTell bmi                                                                     
 | bmi <= 1 = "small"                                                           
 | bmi <= 10 = "medium"                                                         
 | bmi <= 100 = "large"                                                         
 | otherwise "huge"
```

Error info:

```
ghci>:l baby
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( baby.hs, interpreted )

baby.hs:7:1:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: `it doesn't work either` What do you mean by that?

Comment: @thefourtheye added the "error information", it just says `parse error`

Comment: Why are you putting a constraint symbol `=>` in your type signature? It's pointless. The other problem is that you're missing an `=` after that `otherwise`.

Comment: @hanfeisun "parse error" isn't the only thing it says. It also gives you a line and column number, which of course are useless to us as your code snippets don't even contain a line 20.

Comment: @AJFarmar Just found it is a typographical error of the book, <Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!>.  the correct form is `bmiTell :: (RealFloat a) => a -> String`

Comment: The correct form is `bmiTell :: (RealFloat a) => a -> String`. In fact you don't need `RealFloat` for your definition of that function; plain old `Num` will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first case, your type signature is wrong. It should be like this:

```
bmiTell ::  Double -> String  -- Notice that there is no =>
```

In your second case, you are missing `=` in the last line. It should be like this:

```
| otherwise = "huge"  -- Notice the presence of =
```

So a proper working code will look like this:

```
bmiTell ::  Double -> String
bmiTell bmi
  | bmi <= 1 = "small"
  | bmi <= 10 = "medium"
  | bmi <= 100 = "large"
  | otherwise = "huge"
```